# Is it possible to rearrange the order of node inputs based on a driver?

Tags: node-editor

I have the following node group with a handful of surface inputs.

[image]

The object with this material has a custom property that I'd like to keyframe and use as the value of a driver that changes which surfaces are connected to which inputs.

For example, let's say the custom property is an array, [1, 2, 3, 4], which basically says:

- Surface 1 goes to input 1
- Surface 2 goes to input 2
- etc.

If I change the property to instead be [2, 4, 1, 3], I'd like then for:

- Surface 1 to go to input 2
- Surface 2 to go to input 4
- Surface 3 to go to input 1
- Surface 4 to go to input 3

I have a vague understanding that the node graph is an abstraction over the shader that gets generated from the material, so the kind of logic I'm asking for may not even be supported.

This may be possible with a script node, but it seems like Python isn't supported there, just OSL, which is apparently incompatible with GPU rendering, which is what I'm taking advantage of with my RTX 1080Ti. Does this require dropping down to the Python API and creating a custom node?

Comment: Yes, drivers cannot change node connections, only python can manage this task

Comment: There may be a rearrangement of the problem, whereby you index the _surfaces_, and have the material switch according to the index.. that could  be driven?

Comment: @RobinBetts, if that's possible, I'd have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: I'm not clear on the end result yet.. what you mean by 'surface'.. could you give  a toy concrete example of what you want the whole lot to do?